# Print this sequence I just made up

Tags: code-golf, sequence, rational-numbers

To get this sequence I just made up, which will subsequently be referred to as TSIJMU, consider the harmonic series:

\$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} ...\$

But what if you only add a term if it doesn't make the sum so far over 1, and otherwise subtract? Let's see an example here, starting at \$\frac{1}{2}\$:

Sum so far: 0, term: \$ \frac{1}{2} \$

\$  0 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\$, which is less than 1,so we add.

Sum so far: \$ \frac{1}{2} \$, term: \$ \frac{1}{3} \$

\$  \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{6}\$, which is less than 1,so we add.

Sum so far: \$ \frac{5}{6} \$, term: \$ \frac{1}{4} \$

\$  \frac{1}{4} + \frac{5}{6} = \frac{13}{12}\$, which is more than 1,so we subtract, yielding \$\frac{7}{12}\$.

If you do this forever, TSIJMU is the sequence of integers that are *added* when doing this. This goes 2,3,5,6,8, etc.

## Rules

Your code **must not** fail due to floating point errors. As pointed out by Arnauld, this means your code *may* fail due to integer overflow errors. If this is the case, please provide a version which works for arbitrary input size.

As with all [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, there are three ways you can output:

- Take a number \$n\$ and return the nth item of TSIJMU
- Take a number \$n\$ and return the first n items of TSIJMU
- Print TSIJMU infinitely.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

These are 0-indexed, but you can take 1-indexed.

```
0 => 2
3 => 6
9 => 17
25 => 48
58 => 113
90 => 177
156 => 308
352 => 700
479 => 953
```

As requested by Bubbler, the first 20 terms are:

```
2,3,5,6,8,10,12,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,34,36
```

Comment: "your code may fail due to integer overflow errors. If this is the case, please provide a version which works for arbitrary input size" - What do you mean by this?  Does it mean, for instance, that if I answer in R (or any other general-purpose language which will error due to integer overflow eventually), I need to provide a second, independent, program that somehow avoids this effect?  One obvious way to do this would be to import arbitrary-precision libraries, but then I will be changing the 'language' to R+gmp...

Comment: "If you do this forever, TSIJMU is the sequence of integers that are added, stati. This goes 2,3,5,6,8, " Up until that point you described adding fractions. Where do the integers in that sequence come from?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen If you answer in R, your actual submission can just be R, and the non-overflowing version can be as a side note.

Comment: @Anush Sorry, weird typo.

Comment: Ok - I've added a non-overflowing version using arbitrary-precision GMP library, but it's a funny requirement, because (a)  this avoids floating-point errors already, so I probably would have written the function differently from the outset if I wanted to use it, and (b) I can imagine there may be some other languages for which arbitrary-precision arithmetic or unlimited integers are not implemented, and if so it seems a shame to insist on this...

Comment: @Anush I assume it should read "TSIJMU is the sequence of integers whose inverses are added".

Comment: Might be a worthy submission to the OEIS, they don't seem to have it currently...

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 54 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @ovs*
*-4 bytes thanks to @att*

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

```python
a=b=n=2
while a:=a*n+[b,-b][a*n>b!=print(n)]:b*=n;n+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2yTbP1oirPCMzJ1Uh0co2UStPOzpJRzcpNhrItEtStC0oyswr0cjTjLVK0rLNs87TtjX8/x8A)

Although the code is heavily golfed, the idea is a straightforward implementation. `a` and `b` are the numerator and denominator of the current fraction. To add two fractions, we can use a simple formula: `a/b + c/d => (ad + cb) / bd`.

Comment: Heh, I figured Fraction took too much space and a smarter solution could beat a built-in one using the module. +1

Comment: As with hyper's solution, everything can be initialized as 1: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2yTbP1pCrPCMzJ1XB0CrRNlErTzc6SUc3KTYayLRJ0qrTzVO0LSjKzCvRyNOMtU7Sss2zztO2Nfz/HwA). After the second iteration a and b are lower by a factor of 2, but that doesn't change the value of the fraction

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2yTbP1pCrPCMzJ1XB0CpP29bQOtE2UStPOzpJRzcpNhrItEtStC0oyswr0cjTjLVO0rLN@/8fAA)

Comment: @att Very clever; doing it in reverse (and checking if the result is negative). It took me a while to figure out what was going on!

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
W<Goḟε§e+≠1İ\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//9XPEdv4bifzrXCp2Ur4omgMcSwXP//)

An infinite list.

woo, it works.

-2 bytes from ovs.

-4 bytes from Dominic Van Essen.

### Explanation

```
Wo<0-Goḟε§e+`-1İ\
              1İ\ [1/2,1/3,1/4...
      Go      1   scan with 1 as intial value
         §e+`-    [a+b,a-b]
       ḟε         first element <=1
Wo                indices of pairs where
    -             difference is
  <0              < 0 (negative)
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PzzfxkDXPf/hjvnnth5anqqdoGt4ZEPM//8A) by using `1/1` and starting the scan at 1. This removes the need prepend a 0.

Comment: Very nice, didn't know you used husk as well!

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//9XPEfIr2HhuJ/OtcKnZSstMcSwXP//)...

Comment: Make that [13](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//9XPEdv4bifzrXCp2Ur4omgMcSwXP//)...

Comment: I'd been thinking that absdiff didn't work on fractions all this time.. *sigh*

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 45 bytes

```perl6
2.FatRat...{($!+=1/$_)>1??($!-=2/$_)!!.say}&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99Izy2xJCixRE9Pr1pDRVHb1lBfJV7TztDeHsjTtTUC8RQV9YoTK2vVDP//BwA)

Full program that outputs the sequence infinitely.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
#0[#+1/If[++i#>1,-Echo@i,i]]&[i=1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/1/ZIFpZ21DfMy1aWztT2c5QR9c1OSPfIVMnMzZWLTrT1jD2/38A)

Outputs the sequence indefinitely (up to `$IterationLimit`, 4096 by default).

Subtracts terms from 1 instead of adding from 0.

---

Without overriding `$IterationLimit`, **40 bytes**:

```
i=0;Do[i+=1/If[i>1/j,-Echo@j,j],{j,∞}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/T1sDaJT86U9vWUN8zLTrTzlA/S0fXNTkj3yFLJytWpzpL51HHvNrY//8B)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to emanresu A*

```r
c=1
repeat`if`((F=F*(c=c+1)+T)>(T=T*c),F<-F-2*T/c,show(c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9nWkKsotSA1sSQhMy1BQ8PN1k1LI9k2WdtQUztE004jxDZEK1lTx81G103XSCtEP1mnOCO/XCNZU/P/fwA)

Prints the sequence until it reaches the TIO output limit.

The numerator & denominator of the fraction so far are stored in `F` and `T` respectively.  These won't error when they get too large, but [R](https://www.r-project.org/) will assign them as `Inf`, beyond which point every integer will be (incorrectly) output, since `Inf>Inf` is evaluated as `FALSE`.

A non-overflowing version, using **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)+GMP** to handle large integers, is [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9k2xDY9t8DKKrFYLykzvUrDUJPLDVXEQJOrKLUgNbFEISEzLUFDw83WTUsj2TZZ21BTO0TTTiPENkQrWVPHzUbXTddIK0Q/Wac4I79cI1lT8/9/AA) (the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) version installed on TIO seems to give an error, so [here](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=c%3DT%3Dgmp%3A%3Aas.bigz(1)%0AF%3Dgmp%3A%3Aas.bigz(0)%0Awhile(c%3C100)%60if%60((F%3DF*(c%3Dc%2B1)%2BT)%3E(T%3DT*c)%2CF%3C-F-2*T%2Fc%2Cshow(c))%0A) is a link to a working version on rdrr.io, with `repeat` exchanged for `while(c<100)` to force output).

Comment: It appears you don't need the space between `repeat` and `\`if\``?

Comment: @emanresuA - Thanks!  I never realised that before.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
from fractions import*
v=i=Fraction(1)
while 1:i+=1;v-=(v>1/i!=print(i)or-1)/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoAwDAXQ3VPUrVWkBDcljt5DRPGDNiWWiqevi2988U2HhL6UXeUyuy5rgoTb4Iqiqakyg@d/LbnqOXBuhga0TGPu2OaJPGqOipAsnGhHzqOUDw)

-8 bytes thanks to ovs
-1 byte thanks to Jo King (the number can't be exactly 1, also thanks to Bubbler for the pseudo-proof of this)
-2 bytes thanks to att

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcqxCoAgEADQva@wLdOGo626tZ8Qh4jEk1IxMfp6W3rzi2@2wY@1mhQuZtK2Zwr@ZnTFkHLfFCSE5rF0Hgwmh@s/OpDE5yJQDU46rYpwC0KLMZHPHXE9k0Co9QM) by initializing both `v` and `i` as 1 and a slightly shorter conditional expression.

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoAwDAXQ3VPUrbWIBDc1q/cQUfygTYml4unr4htffNMhoS9lV7nMrsuaIOE2uKJoaqrM4PlfS656DpyboSF7ttlTh4mp5qgIycKJtuQ6jPBMpXw)

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoAwDAXQ3VPUrVWkBDcljt5DRPGDNiWWiqevi2988U2HhL6UXeUyuy5rgoTb4Iqiqakyg@d/LbnqOXBuhga0TGPu2OaJPGqOipAsnGhHzqOUDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
«efy}á╤2╧8ßÇæ→╔y¬µ!
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ae6566797da0d132cf38e180911ac979aae621&i=)

Making a husk answer for this turned out to be very difficult. Here's a stack based one for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) `--no-lazy`, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

```
λN*N<!©+DN!‹iN,ë®·-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//867TipOPCHCqStETiHigLlpTizDq8Kuwrct////LS1uby1sYXp5)

There is no builtin fraction type, so everything is integers. (Ab)uses the recursive environment `λ` as an infinite loop that starts the iteration counter `N` at 1 and pushes a `1` to the stack initially.

```python
λ                   # recursive environment
                    # generate infinite sequence of sums starting with a(0)=1
                    # pushes the last value to the stack, lets call this x
 N*                 # push N*x
    N<!©            # calculate (N-1)! and store a copy of the result in the register
        +D          # calculate N*x + (N-1)! and make a copy of the result
          N!‹       # is N*x + (N-1)! < N! ?
             iN,    # if so, N*x + (N-1)! / N! < 1 and print N
             ë®·-   # otherwise subtract (N-1)!*2 to get N*x - (N-1)!
```

Comment: -1 byte by removing the first `D` and changing `\®-` to `®·-`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks a lot. I feel like `–` should be useful here, but the best I can do is the same length: https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX//867TipOPCHCqStETiHigLlE4oCTX2nCrsK3Lf///y0tbm8tbGF6eQ

Comment: Yeah, I was fiddling around with `–` as well when I saw your `iN,`, but was only able to tie it with what you have, or alternatively without if-statement: `D–≠·®*-`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

This prints TSIJMU infinitely:

```perl
$i=1;1while$s+=1/++$i*($s+1/$i<1?say$i:-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l09bQ2rA8IzMnVaVY29ZQX1tbJVNLA8g21FfJtDG0L06sVMm00jXU/P//X35BSWZ@XvF/Xd8yUz1DAwA)

...or until Try It Online reaches its limit of 128 KiB of output. Exploits that `say$i` prints that sequence number and then returns 1.

This is seven bytes longer and takes *n* from stdin:

```perl
$i=1;$s+=1/++$i*($s+1/$i<1?$_--&&say$i:-1)while$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l09bQWqVY29ZQX1tbJVNLA8g21FfJtDG0V4nX1VVTK06sVMm00jXULM/IzElVif//38jgX35BSWZ@XvF/3bz/ur5lpnqGBgA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (with `alert`), 52 bytes

```javascript
for(p=q=i=1n;;p*=i++)q*=i,p*i-p>q?alert(i,q+=p):q-=p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctLCoAgEADQ6/jJoG0xdRYxiwlxZkzC21u0eqt3@cffoSBXl2mP3adYKjRYA@WbUhwTnarpflBRDAIIU14WNoDWavkY2KDjVbZ/KhzEAutZHHDvLw)

Comment: Nice! As specified above, you don't have to use BigInts as you're allowed to error because integer overflow. Please keep this version though.

Comment: [51](https://tio.run/##HctBCoAgEADA72hm0DVZe4uUxYa4uyrR7y26zG2ucIe6FeRmM@2xhxRLgwf8RrlSilOiUz26H1QUgwDCnJ0MgI4/jNE8oGUv6x8VjmKA9SIWuPcX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 47 bytes

```
02s>n[<1f/+1G:![p:lu' o>,<]p[p1l/2*-0]pl`s>]>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/AqNguL9rGME1f29DdSjG6wCqnVF0h307HJrYgusAwR99IS9cgtiAnodgu1k5B4f9/QyMA)

```
02s>n[<1f/+1G:![p:lu' o>,<]p[p1l/2*-0]pl`s>]>
02                                            # Init stack w/ "0" (sum) "2" (divisor)
  s>                                          # Stash the divisor, change to iterator stack
    n                                         # Read number of output items "N" from STDIN
     [                 >,<                >]  # Loop, iterates until "N" is 0
      <                                       # Switch to accumulator stack
       1f/+                                   # Calculate "(1/divisor)+accumulator" 
           1G:                                # Compare "accumulator>=1", duplicate answer
              ![p:        ]p                  # If-then, runs if "accumulator<1"
                  lu' o                       # Load the divisor, print as num, add " "
                       >,<                    # Switch to iterator stack, decr, switch back
                            [p      o]p       # If-then, runs if "accumulator>1"
                              1l/2*-          # Calc "2*(1/divisor)" and subtract
                                       l`s    # Increment divisor, stash it
                                            > # Switch to empty stack to suppress printing
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 51 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹η≔⁰ζ≔¹εＷ‹Ｌυθ«≦⊕ε≧×εζ¿›ζ×η⊖ε≧⁻ηζ«≧⁺ηζ⊞υε»≧×εη»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNC8IwDIbP26/IMYUK6tWTKIjgZIh/oM64Frqq/VCY@Ntr1eHXwRwC4U3ePEklha32Qsc4N4fgl6HZkMUjG@Vj51RtcMBBvqs@h/ZLo1SdpdIEuCDnUjK1lxgYhyNjcMmzQhy69rmpLDVkPG2fg29tpWrpca0ackl6LsnUDnBmSfhE1HJ4qCg5TOnlg8RSwI9PoUxIPrLzIe3oTvK7rtSfXVkZXALvyK5/4O7/uOalVcbjRDifrmWjGIf92DvpGw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔¹η≔⁰ζ≔¹ε
```

Start with a running total of `0/1` and the last fraction as `1/1`.

```
Ｗ‹Ｌυθ«
```

Repeat until enough terms have been collected.

```
≦⊕ε
```

Increment the denominator to get the next unit fraction.

```
≧×εζ
```

Multiply the running total by the denominator.

```
¿›ζ×η⊖ε≧⁻ηζ
```

If incrementing the running total would make it exceed the denominator then decrement it.

```
«≧⁺ηζ⊞υε»
```

Otherwise increment it and push the denominator to the list of results.

```
≧×εη
```

Divide the running total by the denominator.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Print the found terms.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 29 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Just ... hideous!

```
@¶Xõ!÷1 åÈ+Y§1©X+YªnXÃäÎèÉ}a2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=QLZY9SH3MSDlyCtZpzGpWCtZqm5Yw%2bTO6Ml9YTI&input=NDc5)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 108 bytes

```
set s to 0
set i to 2
while 1=1
if(s+(/i))<1
set s to(/i)+s
print i
else
set s to s-(/i)
end if
inc i
repeat
```

Outputs infinitely. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoAgEEX3c4pZKhJl6zpM1IgDYuIIUZc3XdTufd77DyV/51qFCgqWEyfoyB1nuDwHQrtaYKfEqJG1Xix8cd9GIGWO7QIUhH6HMnQNFA9kBxz3VmRKtJVaXw)

Implements the spec directly, using Zephyr's built-in rational numbers. Here it is ungolfed:

```
set sum to 0
set i to 2
while true
    if (sum + (/i)) < 1
        set sum to sum + (/i)
        print i
    else
        set sum to sum - (/i)
    end if
    inc i
repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 26 bytes

```
Wt*:oYt*o>y*Uo?t+y*Poy*o-t
```

Outputs infinitely. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 27-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/vETLKj@yRCvfrlJLWzvfvkS7Uisgv1IrX7fk/38A)

#### Explanation

Pip doesn't have rational numbers, so we'll use integer math instead. We store the numerator of the running sum in `y` (initially `""`, which evaluates to 0 in a numeric context); the denominator in `t` (initially `10`, but any denominator greater than 0 will do, since the numerator is initially 0); and the index in `o` (initially `1`). Each time through the loop, we want to:

- Increment \$o\$
- Test whether \$\frac y t + \frac 1 o \lt 1\$

  - If so, output \$o\$ and add \$\frac 1 o\$ to \$\frac y t\$
  - If not, subtract \$\frac 1 o\$ from \$\frac y t\$

For the test, observe that

$$
 \frac y t + \frac 1 o \lt 1 \\
 \frac{y \cdot o + t}{t \cdot o} \lt 1 \\
 y \cdot o + t \lt t \cdot o \\
 y \cdot o \lt t \cdot (o - 1)
$$

We can combine this expression with the increment of \$o\$ by calculating \$t \cdot o\$ first, then incrementing \$o\$, then calculating \$y \cdot o\$.

For the update, we need

$$
 y := y \cdot o \pm t \\
 t := t \cdot o
$$

Observing that `t*:o` is always truthy, does not depend on the value of `y`, and is a no-op if executed before the first time through the loop, we can use it as the while-loop header.

```
Wt*:oYt*o>y*Uo?t+y*Poy*o-t
                            t is 10, o is 1, y is "" (implicit)
 t*:o                       Multiply t by o and assign the result back to t
W                           and loop while the result is truthy (non-zero):
      t*o>                   Is t*o greater than
            Uo               o, incremented
          y*                 times y?
              ?              If so:
                   Po         Print o
               t+y*           and calculate t+y*o
                             Else:
                     y*o-t    Calculate y*o-t
     Y                       Set y to the calculated value
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC), 75 bytes

```c
n,d,i,j;s(a){for(n=i=1,d=j=2;a/i;n/d?n-=2*d/j:++i)n=n*++j+d,d*=j;return j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLCoMwEEX3fsUgFBITsXXXTod@izi1TKBjibYb8dvTCH2czV3cw@nrW9@npJ69@ICT6ewyjNEoCR08U6AWu0ZQG75oTW3FTTg5J1ZJK@eCY88VBYzX@RkVAq5JdIZ7J2peo7AtlgI@5C6Y7RUg2GOeMxwRthr8rS@PmNXBlDuG0sNkxFr8SWuxpjc)

Overflows when the input is greater than 8.

How it works:

```c
// n is the numerator, d the denominator, i the amount of numbers that have been added and j the denominator of the fraction that is supposed to be added.
n,d,i,j;
s(a)
{
    // The update statement of the for loop is moved to the end of the loop body for clearness (it's executed at the end of the loop anyways).
    // a / i is equivalent to a >= i, so we loop until i is greater than a
    for(n = i = 1, d = j = 2; a / i;)
        // Both n and d are multiplied by j, and the previous value of d is added to n.
        // The new fraction is (n*j + d) / (d*j).
        // (n*j)/(d*j) = n/d, so what's actually added to the fraction is d/(d*j), which can be rewritten as 1/j.
        n = n * ++j + d,
        d *= j,

        // n / d is non-zero iff n >= d, and n >= d iff n/d >= 1
        // If n/d >= 1, subtract what was previously added to n, twice.
        // Otherwise, increment i
        n / d ? n -= 2 * d / j : ++i;
    return j;
}
```

---

This 70-byte version also seems to work, although I'm not sure if it always does:

```c
n,d,i,j;s(a){for(n=i=1,d=j=2;a/i;n/d?n-=2*d/j:++i)n=n*++j+d,d*=j;a=j;}
```

The 70-byte version stores `j` in `a`, which seems to have the same effect as returning `j`. If anyone knows, please tell me if that behavior is consistent and I'm allowed to use it.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCoMwEITvPsUiFBITsfVWt0ufJbhYNtC1aOlF8uxphP4MDHOYj29sb@OYs3r24iOuJthtmhejJHTyTJF6DJ2gdnzVlvqGuzg4J1ZJG@eiY88NRQylKYs@4R5EzWsWttVWwSdFCWZ/BQiOWOYCZ4RdBH/qm8dS0MnUB4baw2rEWvxBqUr5DQ)

---

Here's a 127-byte version that overflows at a number of terms somewhere between 21 and 57:

```c
long long n,d,i,j,k;s(a){for(n=i=1,d=j=2;a/i;n/d?n-=2*d/j:++i){n=n*++j+d,d*=j;for(k=1;k<99;)n%++k||d%k||(n/=k,d/=k);}return j;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LDoJADEX3fEVjQjLDjEHZaW38FkLVdEaLAXWDfDsOxsddnLvoadssT00zTedWT/CGevbig4/Ym9oOx7YzSkJrzxSowroU1JL3uqSq4DJsnRM7KGnhXHDsuaCA81KkNcbdZoNWc@fi88l5gtGSoucEi2N3uN07hYDjJHqDSy1qHq2wzYYMPkmnwMxTAYIVptpBlXp@C3/tm2uX3KNZ5AwLD70Ra/Enjdk4vQA)

It's pretty much the same as the first one, except the variables are long long integers rather than integers, and it includes `for(k=1;k<99;)n%++k||d%k||(n/=k,d/=k);`, which, for each number `k` from 1 to 98, divides `n` and `d` by `k` if they're both divisible by `k`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```hs
p=2#1$0
(n#y)x=(n?y)(x*n)$(n+1)#(y*n)
(n?y)a f|a+y>y*n=f$a-y|1>0=n:f(a+y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcgxCoUwDADQ3VME2iFRhNZRiP8sGSyKGoo6GPDu/cXt8Ra5tnnfS8k8uOhDg@qMHkb9GeHTKnnULpJDq26@FkivdDbV4eSltzdOgXVMWJfKIasCQz5XvcHDLdsMQ4Bc/g)